# Vue Components: Use of <picture> element doesn't work properly

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I tried to use the "picture" element in a Vue component of HTML5 to make older browsers load a larger *.jpg* file instead of the smaller *.webp* file for a newer browser like Chrome and Firefox.

The problem is that after loading the page on browsers with no support for *.webp* images there's no image at all. After inspecting the code in the browser I saw that Vue removed the "picture" element and inserted an "img" element instead.

That's the code that has this behavior:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <picture style="opacity:0.4">
            <source 
                type="image/webp" 
                sizes="width:100% height:12%" 
                srcset="images/background-image-200.webp 3840w 200h">
            <img 
                src="images/background-image-200.jpg"
                sizes="width:100% height:12%">
        </picture>   
    </div>    
</template>
```

I found a workaround for this by forcing Vue to use plain HTML like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div v-html="plainhtml"></div>
    </div>    
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:"index" ,
    props: {

    },
    data () {
      return {
         plainhtml: `
            <picture style="opacity:0.4">
                <source 
                    type="image/webp" 
                    sizes="width:100% height:12%" 
                    srcset="images/background-image-200.webp 3840w 200h">
                <img 
                    src="images/background-image-200.jpg"
                    sizes="width:100% height:12%">
            </picture>    
         ` 
      }
    },

}
</script>
```

But I think this method is not the right way to do this. On larger component files this just gets messy and looks bad code wise.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Are you certain `<img src="images/background-image-200.jpg" 3840w 200h ...` is valid html?

Comment: @kerbholz Ups yeah, I seem to have copied the wrong thing. Edited it. Thx!